# 2013 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2013 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://serverfault.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

---

*Little bit of reasoning/insight*: Iain is stepping down, and needs to be replaced. Server Fault is current moderator heavy in the -4:00 to -8:00 time zones. We would like to get at least one moderator from outside that range (the majority of our long-lived flags come from other timezones, dragging our response time average up).

Also, we have five "active" moderators right now. This number seems to fit the site well, bu if someone goes on holiday/vacation for a week, the others feel the difference. Lives happens, this is an easier job when nobody feels like they're taking the brunt of the firehose.

Comment: More details please. Are we to add more mods or replace current ones? It appeared that we had a [consensus in January](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4140/do-we-need-a-2013-election) that we don't need a 2013 election, so what has changed?

Comment: @SvW This question was automatically generated. Now I know we all talk to our computers, but it's usually profanity-laced exclamations... :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I know, but this question is here and can be commented on, in opposition to the election page, and I reckon either a mod or a SE staff member might see this and chime in.

Comment: @SvW The election page says "moderator positions available: 2". So with Iain throwing in the sponge, this would amount to one surplus position.

Answer (score 11):

I am standing down. The Server Fault that we have today is not the one I was passionate about.

Comment: I'm truly sorry to hear that you're standing down.  I can't say that I disagree with that one-line reason, either, but I'd dearly love to know in a little more detail what you're thinking.  Would you be prepared to expand on your reasoning, even if only a little, in case the community can learn from it?

Comment: I wouldn't want to put words in Iain's mouth, but some people have discussed this at length already (maybe we could formalize it in a Meta post, but I'm not sure what good would come of it). There's a number of factors converging on [SF] which have really changed the "mood" of the site.

Comment: Given the users we've lost recently (and no so recently) and now Iain stepping down I think it would be a good idea to start a meta thread about the changing dynamic of the site.

Comment: I know we haven't always seen eye to eye about certain things, but you've been a very positive influence here. I mean, hell, you organized sending a card halfway around the world for my wedding to a guy that most of the signers have never met in person. I'm not sure whether to upvote this or downvote it :) Either way, sad to see you go and I hope you stick around.

Comment: @MadHatter: SF is no longer by professionals for professionals it is by professionals for amateurs and if you try to fix it then you're considered hostile and unfriendly - sums up why I'm standing down.

Comment: So your problem is the site isn't exclusionary or elitist enough? Thanks for your service, but good riddance. Today's amateurs are tomorrows professionals. We should cater to anyone interested in the profession, and not just those privileged enough to be working in such an easy career.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Yes, that put's a bow on it. Today's amateurs are tomorrow's amateurs, or worse, cargo cult administrators. Today's amateurs who Read The Friendly Documentation are tomorrow's Experts. Super User is for spoon-feeding amateurs, not Server Fault.